# Jquery onclick on div

Tags: jquery

I have a simple question. The following code works for all the tags:

```
$('*').click(function(e) {  
    alert(1);
});
```

But, when I try this code for the div with id "content":

```
$('#content').click(function(e) {  
    alert(1);
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't know, what are you doing wrong (as in the error/unexpected)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Make sure it's within a document ready tagAlternatively, try using `.live`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#content').live('click', function(e) {  
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').click(function(e) {  
      alert(1);
    });
});
```

```css
#content {
    padding: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Hello world</div>
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

```
$('#content').on( "click", function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Nothing.

```
$('#content').click(function(e) {  
    alert(1);
});
```

Will bind to an *existing* HTML element with the ID set to `content`, and will show a message box on click.

- Make sure that `#content` exists before using that code
- That the ID is **unique**
- Check your Javascript console for any errors or issues

Answer (score 3):

js

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").on('click', function(){
            console.log("click!!!");
        });
});

</script>
```

html

```
<div id="div1">div!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May the div with id="content" not be created when this event is attached? You can try live() jquery method.

Else there may be multiple divs with the same id or you just spelled it wrong, it happens...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in `$(document).ready()` method or `$()`.

```
$(function(){

$('#content').click(function(e) {  
    alert(1);
});

});
```

Comment: Whenever you want to find any element or attach event handler to dom elements make sure you do it in `$()` or `$(document).ready()` method. `$("*")`  works because it attachs event to the document and uses event bubling mechanism to execute the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GP3sK/) ... you're doing it correctly. Make sure the id is content and also check to see there are no other elements with the same id. If there are multiple elements with the same id, it will bind to the first one. That might be why you arn't seeing it.

Comment: Thanks, another thing I forgot to mention is that any other tag doesn't work (body, html etc..)