# How to get div clicked part in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replicate something like a volume slider or video seekbar where, when the user clicks a point, the indicator jumps to that location.

To do that, I am trying to get the position of a click event on a `div`. When user clicks somewhere on my div I am trying to return `x`, `y` coords.

So far I just have a `div` and a basic listener:

```
<div class="heybro" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:black;"></div>

$('.heybro').click(function(){
    alert("something");
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery how to get click coordinates on the target element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234977/using-jquery-how-to-get-click-coordinates-on-the-target-element)

Comment: You can add element on this position and add the event listener top it

Comment: You can refer this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034342/jquery-onclick-on-div

Comment: There is no "onclick" in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `event` object in your click handler:

```js
$('.heybro').click(function(e) {
  console.log("click location in page:");
  console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  var offset = $(this).offset()
  console.log("click location in div:");
  console.log(e.pageX - offset.left, e.pageY - offset.top);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heybro" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:black;"></div>
```

Take a look at this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236129/123415

Comment: Thanks it works, But my `e.pageY` value show like 472 when I click at position 20th.

Comment: O.k I think it's showing the position of the `body` other than my `div` element position, Can you tell me why is it doing that. FYI: I am Using exact same code as you said above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".heybro").onclick(function() {
        var $clicker = $(this);
        var pos = $clicker.position();
        console.log(pos.top);
        console.log(pos.left);
    });
```

Editted to clearly explanation, for anyone who might want to understand how it works.

```
var $clicker = $(this);
```

The $clicker variable is initialised, created a new special jQuery object. We need to do so in order to use the second method, jQuery.position, to create a new variable with the top offset and left offset of the click.

```
var pos = $clicker.position();
```

We can now access the "top" and "right" properties, which indicate the position where the user clicked, relative to the top and left coordinates.